# Blender Shading not working with Principled BSDF

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, shaders

Why is my shader not working correctly? I keep getting the same problem over and over when trying to use a BSDF in shading (it worked a few months ago).
Updated blender but nothing helped.

[image: This works] [image: This isn't working]

Shading with only Color works perfectly fine.

When adding Principled BSDF nothing happens and after reloading nothing affects this Color.

Cant get any Texture or anything to Work with shaders, even the default cube won't change its Color with the default shader and change

When rendering with the bsdf activated the output is only a cube without texture

[image: failed render]

Comment: Let me guess: AMD GPU?

Comment: Thanks now it works